# Javascript regex array does not match

Tags: javascript, regex

My pattern stops after the first match and it has the global match in there.

```
//When I add [*]* like var pattern=/([^A-z0-9]|^|[*]*)_(\S.*?)_((?!\S)|\W)/g;
//  it works, but when I try to match "1_test1_" and "a_test1_" it matches "_test1_"
//  which I don't want. I know [*]* will match 0 or more instances of literal *
//  but [*]+ won't work due to the first match being "_test1_*"

var pattern=/([^A-z0-9]|^)_(\S.*?)_((?!\S)|\W)/g;

alert("_test1_*_test2_".match(pattern)); //=> _test1_*
    //This should match "_test1_*" first then it should also add to the array with "_test2_"
```

**QUESTION START**

I want the above *(first code block)* to alert "_test1_*,_test2_" 
and I want the below *(second code block)* to remain the same (as shown by the commentend section).

I don't know why _test2_ does not match because it matches perfectly with the tests shown below.

**QUESTION FINISH**

The following are tests and work as they should.

```
alert("_test1_ _test2_".match(pattern)); //=> _test1_, _test2_
alert("_test1_*".match(pattern)); //=> _test1_*
alert("_test2_".match(pattern)); //=> _test2_
alert("*_test2_".match(pattern)); //=> *_test2_
alert("1_test1_".match(pattern)); //=> null
alert("a_test1_".match(pattern)); //=> null
alert("_test1_1".match(pattern)); //=> null
alert("_test1_a".match(pattern)); //=> null
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Can you edit your question to make the actual problem more clear?

Comment: The top code gives an array with \_test1_* but I want it to have [0] = \_test1_* and [1] = \_test2_

Comment: It's just all so confusing. Please don't post unless you have a good specification of what you want. Then go ahead and try to structure you question so it's understandable. (To only slightly get a clue of what your problem is, I have to jump up and down wildly in your question)

Comment: I don't see what's so confusing. All I want is the above pattern (which is not commented out) to make "\_test1_*\_test2_".match(pattern) with the outcome \_test1_*,\_test2_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After numerous trial and error attempts I have finally found my answer by adding |\b. Thank you @Alih Nehpets for your attempts at answering my question.

```
([^A-z0-9]|^|\b)_(\S.*?)_((?!\S)|\W)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think pattern should be changed. How about this? Put a question mark after the part where you want an optional symbol character before underscore:

```
([^A-z0-9]|^)?_(\S.*?)_((?!\S)|\W)
```

Comment: That makes "\_test_*_test_" into array(\_test_*,\_test_) which is what I want. However, it changes "1_test1_" and "a_test1_" into array(\_test_) which is not what I want (this array should be null). Thanks for your attempt though.

Comment: The information before the first underscore can either be the start of a new line, white-space or a non-alphanumeric character !@#$%^&*() and \_

Comment: I see, does cause problem. Does this mean if the first char sequence is wrong then no sequences should be returned in the array..?

Comment: @AlihNehpets - Welcome to stackoverflow. Tip, you can format code snippets using the `{ }` icon on the toolbar or for inline code using back-ticks ie `

Comment: Yes, ([^A-z0-9]|^) is not optional. If the sequence is found elsewhere in the string then it can give an array.

Comment: @Reuben1st I see. Hmm wierd problem. In your test, when you replace the asterisk with a space, it works.. I'll try something else..

Comment: @Leigh Thanks Leigh, I didn't notice the toolbar above.

Comment: Welcome. (I did not see the code button the first time round either :)

Comment: @Leigh Really :D Will use it in the next answer then :D

Answer (score 0):

Ok then how about using this sequence, dunno if its what you're lookin for:

`([^A-z0-9]|^|)_(\S.*?)_((?!\S)|\W)`

I just added an extra vert line after the start-of-string symbol in the regex, was testing your non-working case and works.

BTW, I use regexpal.com for testing up regexes.

Comment: Sorry, above still doesn't work. Maybe a workaround is to append a space every after two underscores, this kind of a wierd problem..

Comment: Yeah I tried adding the | (pipe) before I posted this question. I only posted this question because I have literally no idea why I only get one match. I use [http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/) which has a nice desktop version.

Comment: I see. Yeah its really confusing why there's only one match. Wild guess, its treating first match as invalid start to the second since pattern's restricting to only symbol-character before first underscore. Sorry wasn't able to help, hope someone posts a solution to this intriguing problem.